# VueJS: Building dynamic src path for Vuetify v-img

Tags: image, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am using `v-for` to display collection of images using `Vuetify` `v-img`. We only store the image's Id which is then dynamically inserted into the `src` attribute of `v-img`. But dynamically inserting `src` value is not working. `image.title` is displayed but nothing is displayed for `v-img`. I have tried few other answers on SO but none worked. Does anybody know what is the correct way to do this?

```
<v-card max-width="400" v-for="image in images" :key="image.sourceId">
  {{image.title}}
  <v-img
      src="'https://img.imagestore.com/image/' + image.sourceId + '.jpg'">
  </v-img>
</v-card>

export default {
  data: () => ({
    images: [
      {
        id: "2",
        sourceId: "bMwG1R3sXnE",
        title: "Sunrise"
      },
      {
         id: "3",
         sourceId: "pqrwG1R3sXnE",
         title: "Amazon Forest"
      }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, binding the `src` attribute made it work so instead of `src` use `:src`

```
  <v-img
    :src="'https://img.imagestore.com/image/' + image.sourceId + '.jpg'">
  </v-img>
```

or

```
  <v-img
    :src="`https://img.imagestore.com/image/${image.sourceId}.jpg`">
  </v-img>
```

Comment: Great! Any kind of binding you have to give ```:```

Comment: this is shorthand for `v-bind:src`